# How to display an image stored as a BLOB?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, imageview, blob

I stored an image in an SQLite database using Android Studio:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL(create_table);
    }

private static final String create_table = "create table if not exists Test ("+
            "EntryID integer primary key autoincrement, "+
            "Description string,"+
            "Picture blob"+
            ")";
```

Insert into database :

```
ContentValues cv5 = new ContentValues();
    cv5.put("EntryID",1);
    cv5.put("Description","The club was founded in 1885";
    cv5.put("Picture","club.png");
    sdb.insert("Test",null,cv5);
```

Attempting to display stored image:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.club);
    image.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
}
```

I get an error that a drawable is expected.

Answer (score 1):

> > cv5.put("Picture","club.png"); // it's a WRONG way

You need previously convert image to BLOB, something like that

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outStreamArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.common)).getBitmap();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStrea);   
    byte[] photo = outStreamArray.toByteArray();cv5.put("Picture", photo)
```

After that you need decode BLOB to image

```
  byte[] photo=cursor.getBlob(index of blob cloumn);
ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(photo);
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. Where are you decoding the Blob to an image? I cannot add it without getting "Non static method getBlob(int) cannot be referenced from a static context"